# \documentclass[11pt][reqno]{amsbook} fails to compile with File .cls not found

Tags: fontsize, document-classes

I don't see a similar question so I'm posting this.

The file compiles fine if I delete [11pt] and let it default to 10pt.

- I believe the format \documentclass[11pt][reqno]{amsbook} is correct
- I believe 11pt is compatible with the document class amsbook
- I did not read of a conflict between [regno] and typeface size

If it matters, the compiler is `MikTex`.

Comment: Write `\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook}` instead of `\documentclass[11pt][reqno]{amsbook}`.

Comment: To generalize the previous comments, options on `\documentclass` must all be enclosed in the same set of brackets `[ ]` and separated by commas.  (The options you wish to use are both defined; it's the input format that's not correct.)

Comment: Thank you all. Clearly, I was wrong - the format is incorrect. If one you would like to post the clarification as an answer I'll be happy to check it and add a point. BTW, the entry in my list of commands for \documentstyle doesn't say anything about all the options being inside one set of [ ] separated by commas. How do you folks find out these things!

Comment: any documentation that you have seen that said you could use `[11pt]`  should have said what the syntax was, so the question is more where have you seen any suggestion that two options are possible there, we could get that documention fixed.

Comment: A 14-page pdf titled Latex Command Summary. To be clear it isn't clear either way - I just read it one way. The entry reads:  //   \documentstyle[substy]{sty} determines default font, headings, etc., for document of style sty (and optional substyle substy). Styles: article, book, letter, report,
slides. Substyles: 11pt, 12pt, acm, draft, fleqn, leqno, twocolumn, twoside.  // I don't know where I got it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I did a quick Google on "list of latex commands" and found the same pdf on several sites, so it's out there, likely it's an appendix to a Latex manual. And, of course, it's not wrong, just not a clear as it could be. But I also found the NASA GISS site with all of the commands. It remarked on the need for commas if more than one option. So, I've book-marked it and I think that will be my go-to from now on and perhaps I won't have to bother folks with completely avoidable syntax errors. Thanks again to all.

Comment: `\documentstyle` !!!!!!  we replaced `\documentstyle` by  `\documentclass` when we  introduced latex2e in 1993. You just missed out on 30 years of LaTeX devlopment.

Comment: try https://learnlatex.org

Comment: The story of my life. If there's an "approved" guide, manual, list, or whatever, it might be good to to post it for the Rip Van Winkles of the world.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Ignore my previous post., I didn't see your follow up reference. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first optional argument of `\documentclass` takes a comma separated list of options.

So:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

If you enter

```
\documentclass[11pt][reqno]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Then essentially LaTeX sees

```
\documentclass[11pt]{}[
```

and fails to find a class file with empty name.

With an old release (2019 or older) you get the error

```
 LaTeX Error: File `.cls' not found.
```

With a current release, you get several internal errors as the new filehooks code fails on the empty filename.

```
! LaTeX hooks Error: Missing (empty) default label on line 1.
(hooks)              This command was ignored.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \documentclass[11pt][r
                          eqno]{amsbook}
?
```